# Diablo 3 Hardcore Character just died during a 10+ second lag spike, will I be able to get him back?

Tags: diablo-iii

Question really says it all.

I was doing fine for about an hour. Beat Act I on normal, killed the Butcher by myself, then started Act II.

Just as I entered the desert with the Enchantress I hit a lag spike which lasted about 10+ seconds where I saw two enemies on the screen and I knew this was not good. So I quickly alt-F4'd only to come back and find my character dead and unable to play.

I know Blizzard is strict about Hardcore characters, but is there really no compensation for death due to lag? What if it were the Battle.net servers that caused the lag spike?

Comment: Sorry. Here, have some rep instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the manual of Diablo 2

> Note: Blizzard Entertainment is in no way responsible for your
>   Hardcore character. If you choose to create and play a Hardcore
>   character, you do so at your own risk. Blizzard is not responsible for
>   the death and loss of your hardcore characters for any reason
>   including Internet lag, bugs, Acts of God, your little sister, or any
>   other reason whatsoever. Consult the End User License Agreement for
>   more details. Blizzard will not, and does not have the capability to
>   restore any deceased Hardcore characters. Don't even ask.
>   La-la-la-la-la, we can't hear you...

Probably carries over to Diablo 3.

Comment: LA-LA-LA-LA-LA WE CAN'T HEAR YOU

Answer (score 15):

Nope. No compensation. This is what hardcore mode is all about. It encourages a much more conservative play style, and much more attention to the performance of your computer.

If you can't take the heat, stay out of the kitchen.

Comment: If I got paralyzed in a car wreck because I was hit by a drunk driver, that would be like telling me that I should be more careful driving.

Comment: Except in this case you willingly chose to drive on a road known for its drunk drivers that refuse to obey the speed limits, every night, since the road was opened, and acknowledged a warning that if you did you were probably going to be hit by one of them. Hardcore simply isn't designed to be fair - it's designed to eventually screw you if anything slips up. Some people enjoy that risk. I'm not one of them.

Comment: I *do* enjoy the risk of hardcore. The risk that the game intended (death due to in-game mechanics - not internet woes or busy servers). I know I'm fighting a lost cause at this point... mainly venting, but there is nothing "hardcore" about internet lag or dropped packets causing death. Oh well at least someone can hear me out.

Comment: Death due to internet woes or busy servers are *part of the risk of hardcore*. This has always been the case, and is nothing new in Diablo 3, contrary to popular belief.

Comment: Fine. All I want at this point is sympathy. :'(

Comment: I don't think anyone disagrees that it's a lame, boring, frustrating way to die - but there's just no alternative and no recourse and no way we can really help you. It sucks, but, that's Hardcore for you.

Comment: @Microsis And my sympathies you have. But honestly, that heightened sense of risk that something can happen at *any* time -  even for reasons outside of the game world -  is what makes Hardcore so exciting.

Comment: I Have yet to play hardcore, but I feel like I would make it to *maybe* act II before dying and then rage-quitting the game lol

Comment: Try not to worry about it. Losing a character to lag definitely stings, but any permadeath game works just the same way; you can (and will) die to stuff outside of your control sometimes. If you can, try to take a laid-back attitude about losing characters, and play more for the general moment-to-moment excitement of Hardcore play than anything else. All you can do is say "darn it" and start a new character. :) (And for the record, I lost my own 47 DH just last night to lag, so I sympathize.)

Comment: I would like to point out that (unless I am somehow missing something???) one did not have to worry about network lag "causing" a hardcore character to die in Diablo 2 single player, because you did not have to be connected to Blizzard - this connection requirement is at least new to the Diablo universe, is it not?

Comment: @CodeJockey 'offline' hardcore play is essentially meaningless, as it is trivially circumvented. It basically amounts to some stern red text telling you not to play that character again. More to the point, in D2, Hardcore play was primarily driven by the ranked ladder, which required that you play online.